# Fortran Getting inputs from a file

Tags: file, fortran, bubble-sort

I have a Fortran code that gets integers from users, sorts them in descending order with bubble sort, then writes it into a file. However, in the beginning, instead of getting the integers from users, I have to get them from a file. How can I do that? Could you please help me? Thanks.

```
PROGRAM project
   IMPLICIT NONE
   INTEGER array(1000),t,p,c 
   PRINT*,"Enter 1000 element array"
   READ*,array 
   c=1
   OPEN(UNIT=25,FILE="sorted.txt")
   DO p=1,999
      DO c=1,999
         IF (array(c)>array(c+1)) then 
           t=array(c)
           array(c)=array(c+1)
           array(c+1)=t
         ENDIF
      ENDDO
   ENDDO
   WRITE(98,*) array
   CLOSE(98)
   PRINT*,array(2:999)
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, you open the file to write the output to as unit 25:

```
OPEN(UNIT=25,FILE="sorted.txt")
```

But you write and close unit 98:

```
WRITE(98,*) array
CLOSE(98)
```

Is this an error in your question, otherwise you might want to investigate.

That said, if you are running the program from a shell like bash, the easiest way is to use the output redirecting:

```
$ cat unsorted.txt > sort.exe
```

That way you don't have to change anything in your code.

If you don't want to do that, you need to open and read from the file in your program:

```
open(unit=24, file='unsorted.txt', action='READ', &
     status='OLD', form="FORMATTED")
read(24, *) array
close(24)
```

This assumes that the file with the unsorted data contains exactly 1000 integers and nothing else.